# Keystore file doesn't exist. Unable to get SHA1 key

Tags: ionic-framework, sha1, google-authentication

Unable to get SHA1 key, it is showing error about path, Keystore file doesn't exist.

Tried multiple numbers of solutions,
I am using the following command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore c:\users\your_user_name\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Comment: what's the error ?

Comment: Keystore file does not exist: c:\users\your_user_name\.android\debug.keystore
'java.lang.Exception:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: And does the file exist ?

Comment: i don't know,,,i guess yess the file exists but i didn't get the path

Comment: you have the path in error, just check on your computer ...

Comment: Nothing Found ,i'd tried my level best

Comment: So you got your solution : the keystore file does not exists, you have to create one. You'll find a lot of resources on SO or Google to do it ;)

Comment: Ty, i just understand my mistake :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keystore file does not exists, you have to create it yourself.

Here is the procedure : [Generate android release and debug keystores](https://coderwall.com/p/r09hoq/android-generate-release-debug-keystores)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but I tried below command and interestingly it worked for me under Windows 10.

```
keytool -list -keystore debug.keystore
```